Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\...\150\Binn\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variable'
I have an SSIS package created in Visual Studio 2019 and added a Script Task with 3 ReadOnlyVariables. When I execute the control flow, I get the error:
Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\150\Binn\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variable'.
I am really perplexed by this. What DLL is supposed to include Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variable?

Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variable isn't a file, as suggested by the error message, but rather a class in the Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime namespace.
There isn't much info to go on here, but my best guess is that your script contains something like this:
someVariable.ToString()

when what you mean is this:
someVariable.Value

If this doesn't help, could you post some more information, or debug by thinning out your script and posting a minimal reproducible example?
